# Nancy Selfhosting and google authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, nancy

I can't find any proper sample about
google (or facebook) authentication in case of using Nancyfx as a Self-Hosting program.

Advice needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry there is no official code/sdk for Nancyfx.
But if you want to support basic "Sign in with Google" on any site the easiest is to add some code on the page (this can get you an id_token)
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

And send this id_token to your server and validate it on the server side. The code to validate is fairly simple. You can pick up the sample python or java code from here.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

This is probably the easiest way to get Google sign-in on a web based application.

Comment: Oh cool. And how about signing from Android and call nancyfx server with oAuth ?

Comment: Yes, same id_token works. see this  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html   You can get an id_token and send it to the server.

Comment: Most perfect comment you made. Many Thanks.